# How to get row and column number from crossgrid data

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

[image]

Cross Grid Data

I have answer list like:

1. Program
2. Target // like so on....

I try below code but its not work

```
List<AnswerPosition> answerPositions = new List<AnswerPosition>();
                for (int k=0; k < rows; k++)
                {
                    string answer = answers[k];
                    int colStart = GetColumnStart(board, k, answer);

                    if (colStart >= 0)
                    {
                        answerPositions.Add(new AnswerPosition
                        {
                            Answer = answer,
                            Row = k,
                            ColumnStart = colStart,
                            ColumnEnd = colStart + answer.Length - 1
                        });
                    }
                }
```

I need to find out the Ans starting column in row and ending column number in row

how I will find out?

Comment: Can you format your question better? It's not clear what you are trying to achive. Do you want to create a Crossgrid or do you already have one and try to find the answers?

Comment: i have crossgrid, i have to find out ans position in row and column of ans

Comment: Can you provid the input data as text instead of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step 1 - Loading input data into a 2D array

```cs
string[] words = {"Cake", "Gold", "Goal"};
List<string> inputRows = new List<string>{
    "*,*,C,*,*", 
    "G,o,a,l,*", 
    "*,*,k,*,*", 
    "*,*,e,*,*", 
    "*,G,o,l,d", };

int rows = inputRows.Count;
int cols = inputRows[0].Split(',').Length;
char[, ] crosswordGrid = new char[rows, cols];
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    string[] rowElements = inputRows[row].Split(',');
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
    {
        crosswordGrid[row, col] = rowElements[col][0];
    }
}
```

#### Step 2 (optional) - Verify your data

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < crosswordGrid.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < crosswordGrid.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write(crosswordGrid[i, j] + "\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

#### Step 3 (optional) - Find `words` in array

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    string word = words[i];
    for (int row = 0; row < crosswordGrid.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < crosswordGrid.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            if (crosswordGrid[row, col] == word[0])
            {
                bool foundWord = true;
                // Check if word fits across
                if (col + word.Length <= crosswordGrid.GetLength(1))
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < word.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (crosswordGrid[row, col + j] != word[j])
                        {
                            foundWord = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (foundWord)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Across: {0} ", word);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                foundWord = true;
                // Check if word fits down
                if (row + word.Length <= crosswordGrid.GetLength(0))
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < word.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (crosswordGrid[row + j, col] != word[j])
                        {
                            foundWord = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (foundWord)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Down: {0}", word);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Step 4 - Find the `word` starting and ending Column number in a Row

This code will only print the starting and ending column numbers of each word in a row. You just have to invert it to get the words down.

```cs
for (int row = 0; row < crosswordGrid.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < crosswordGrid.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        // Check for word start
        if (col == 0 || crosswordGrid[row, col - 1] == '*')
        {
            int startCol = col;
            StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
            // Find the end of the word and store the characters
            while (col < crosswordGrid.GetLength(1) && crosswordGrid[row, col] != '*')
            {
                word.Append(crosswordGrid[row, col]);
                col++;
            }

            int endCol = col - 1;
            // Print the starting and ending column numbers of the word, and the word itself
            if(words.Contains(word.ToString()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Row {row + 1}: Word '{word}' starts at column {startCol + 1} and ends at column {endCol + 1}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[dotnet Fiddle for this Solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b1927u)

Comment: your code finding only  for words ,can you please help me

Comment: what else do you looking for?

Comment: @rani also please avoid begging and try to provid constructive input/or format your questions better.

Answer (score 1):

You input looks like strings so use code like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication52
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = @"
                                  'C,a,l,l,C,A,v,o,i,d,a,n,c,e,*,*,*,*,*',
                                  '*,*,*,*,h,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*',
                                  '*,*,*,*,u,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,P,*',
                                  '*,*,*,*,r,*,*,T,*,*,*,*,*,L,*,*,*,r,*',
                                  '*,*,*,*,n,*,*,a,*,*,*,*,B,a,c,k,l,o,g',
                                  '*,*,*,*,*,*,T,r,e,n,d,*,*,g,*,*,*,g,*',
                                  'A,*,*,*,R,*,*,g,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,C,*,r,*',
                                  't,*,*,*,a,*,*,e,*,*,*,*,*,T,*,a,*,a,*',
                                  't,*,*,*,t,*,S,t,a,f,f,*,*,i,*,l,*,m,*',
                                  'r,*,*,*,e,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,m,*,l,*,*,*',
                                  'i,*,*,*,*,S*,*,*,*,*,*,*,e,*,*,*,*,*,*',
                                  ,t,*,E,x,c,e,p,t,i,o,n,s,*,*,*,F,C,R,*',
                                  ,i,*,*,*,*,r,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,o,*,*,*',
                                  ,o,*,*,*,*,v,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,r,*,*,*',
                                  ,n,*,*,A,g,i,n,g,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,c,*,*,*',
                                  ,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,i,*,*,*',
                                  '*,*,*,*,W,e,b,*,C,h,a,t,*,*,*,n,*,*,*',
                                  '*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,g,*,*,*'
                             ";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            List<List<string>> crossGrid = new List<List<string>>();
            string line = "";
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim(new char[] { ' ', ',' });
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                    crossGrid.Add(new List<string>(splitLine));
                }
            }
        }
    }

 
}
```